# Here map event equivalent to Google Map “idle” event

Tags: here-api

I can't seem to find the map event in Here that equals to Google Map "idle" event.

The definition of Google Map event "idle" is "This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming."

So, when any of the map actions are done completely the map becomes idle and the `idle` event is fired — with this event i can guarantee all map's animations, actions and other stuff are done completely.

For example, if i zoom or pan the map with the animation option enabled `zoom_changed` and `dragend` events will be fired immediately but only after the `idle` event i can safely use `getZoom` or `getBounds` or `getCenter` methods and get correct values instead of some intermediate values (while animation is still running).

In Here maps i can see only pointer, drag and tap events. There is no any zoom change event at all. And all those events cannot guarantee the map is ready to give correct zoom/bounds/center/etc values after some interaction.

For example, Here `dragend` event is firing but drag animation is still running, so i cannot guarantee `getBounds` or `getCenter` will return correct values if i try to read them right in `dragend` callback.

In Yandex maps i have `actionend` event which is equivalent to the Google's "idle" event.

What i have in Here maps which is equal to the Google Map or Yandex Map "idle" event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the JavaScript API you may want to look at the `mapviewchangeend` [event](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map.html#h-map__mapviewchangeend-event)